# How to solve this dynamic programming puzzle on matrix?

Tags: dynamic-programming, combinatorics, matrices

We are given 4 integers N,M ,Q and Z.

Initially,the matrix has all zeroes in it.

We have to perform Q operations on the matrix.

In each operation, any cell of the matrix can be selected(same cell can be selected multiple times) .

Once a cell (x,y) is selected, you have to add  '1'  to all the elements of row 'x' and column 'y' .

After all the operations are done , there should be exactly "Z" numbers in the matrix which are odd.

How many sequences of Q-operations are possible for given $N,M,Q,Z$

Example:-

N=2,M=2,Q=2,Z=0

Answer:- 8

If we start by choosing the cell (1,1), the matrix becomes

2 1

1 0

Now we have two options ― we can choose either even-valued cell. If we choose (1,1) again, the matrix becomes

4 2

2 0

If we choose (2,2) instead, it becomes

2 2

2 2

For each of the other three possible initial cells, there are also two cells we can choose in the second operation, which is 4⋅2=8 ways in total.

$N$ and $M$ are dimensions of the matrix.

What have I tried:-

Number of ways to select 'Q' distinct points on a matrix:-

$^{N*M}C_{Q}$

Number of ways to select 'Q' points on a matrix with repetition allowed:-

$^{N*M+Q}C_{Q}$

Comment: Which approaches have you tried? Where did you get stuck? I guess with N and M describe the dimension of the matrix. oh should clarify this in your post.

Comment: This appears to be taken from an ongoing coding contest: https://www.codechef.com/OCT19A/problems/JIIT.  Parts of this appear to be copied word-for-word from that source.   [Plagiarism](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715) -- we require people to credit the source of all copied material.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115680/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388035/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).